# DataCloneError on Loading Native App on Firefox MacOS

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I am trying to build a Firefox extension using [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) on MacOS.

I was referring to this [example](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/main/native-messaging).
When I have only one line in my `background.js`:

```
let port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");
```

Loading the extension gives the following errors:

```
DataCloneError: Exception object could not be cloned. subprocess_worker_common.js:203:15
    onmessage resource://gre/modules/subprocess/subprocess_worker_common.js:203
NotSupportedError: ClonedErrorHolder constructor: We can only clone DOM Exceptions and native JS Error objects: onConnect/<@resource://gre/modules/NativeMessaging.sys.mjs:140:48
handler@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.sys.mjs:91:19
emit@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.sys.mjs:154:20
_cleanup@resource://gre/modules/NativeMessaging.sys.mjs:291:12
NativeApp/this.startupPromise<@resource://gre/modules/NativeMessaging.sys.mjs:116:14
EventEmitter.sys.mjs:158
undefined NativeMessaging.sys.mjs:115
    startupPromise resource://gre/modules/NativeMessaging.sys.mjs:115
```

I am not sure if Firefox is bugged.

- Firefox version: 118.0.2 (64-bit)
- MacOS: Ventura 13.5.1

Comment: Maybe the people on https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/add-ons/development/108 can help you.